# edit columnnames that include duplicate special characters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have some column names that include two question marks at different spaces e.g. 'how old were you? when you started university?' - i need to identify which columns have two question marks in. any tips welcome! thanks

**data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'how old were you? when you started university?': [1,2,3,4,5], 'how old were you when you finished university?': [1,2,3,4,5], 'at what age? did you start your first job?': [1,2,3,4,5]})
```

**expected output**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'how old were you when you finished university?': [1,2,3,4,5]})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea with list comprehension:

```
df = df[[c for c in df.columns if c.count("?") < 2]]
print (df)
   id  how old were you when you finished university?
0   1                                               1
1   2                                               2
2   3                                               3
3   4                                               4
4   5                                               5
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use boolean-indexing:

```py
x = df.loc[:, df.columns.str.count(r"\?") < 2]
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
   id  how old were you when you finished university?
0   1                                               1
1   2                                               2
2   3                                               3
3   4                                               4
4   5                                               5
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all columns that have more than one question mark, you can use the following:

`[c for c in df.columns if c.count("?")>1]`

Edit: If you want to replace the extra "?" but keep the ending "?", use this:

`df.rename(columns = {c: c.replace("?", "")+"?" for c in df.columns if c.find("?")>0})`

Answer (score 1):

```
df = df.drop([col for col in df.columns if col.count("?")>1], axis=1)
```